# Concat and to column

Tags: mysql, sql

How do add the concatenated firstname column and lastname column from a table with 100 rows and then add it fullname column each of the concatenated first name and last name

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`fullname`) VALUES (CONCAT(first_name,last_name))
```

What it did is that it added a new row with nothing in it it didn't add each row of 100.
What I want is that for each of the rows of first and last name there is a fullname that is concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to do an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `fullname` = CONCAT(first_name,last_name)
```

Assuming that you've already added the column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD `fullname` VARCHAR(60)
```

Comment: Thank you it wokrs will be top answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to have it readable, I'd guess, so your query should look like this:

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `fullname` = CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
```

Without the center quotes with an empty space, it'll be "first_namelast_name" as opposed to "first_name last_name"